# how to ignore ivy revision number?

Tags: ivy

I have certain jar files without revision number. But as rev is mandatory attribute for ivy dependency, I am providing the revision attribute. But I have something like (`-[revision]`) in url resolver.
But its taking the module number instead of ignoring the revision attribute. I know it won't ignore the revision attribute as its not null.

Following is the output that i get

```
 default-cache: no cached resolved revision for perltools#perltools;latest.integration
[ivy:retrieve]      tried httP://myrepo/ivyRepository/perltools/jars/[revision]/perltools-[revision].jar
[ivy:retrieve]  listing all in httP://myrepo/ivyRepository/perltools/jars/[revision]/perltools-[revision].jar
[ivy:retrieve]  using privateRepo to list all in httP://myrepo/ivyRepository/perltools/jars/
[ivy:retrieve] ApacheURLLister found URL=[httP://myrepo/ivyRepository/perltools/jars/perltools.jar].
[ivy:retrieve]      found 1 resources
[ivy:retrieve]  found revs: [perltools.jar]
[ivy:retrieve] HTTP response status: 404 url=httP://myrepo/ivyRepository/perltools/jars/perltools.jar/perltools-perltools.jar.jar
[ivy:retrieve] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=httP://myrepo/ivyRepository/perltools/jars/perltools.jar/perltools-perltools.jar.jar
```

Can somebody please explain why its taking module.ext as revision where revision I specified is latest.integration and in myrepo,Ii dont have revision attribute.

It just has

```
[http://myrepo/ivyRepository/perltools/jars//perltools.jar]
```

Can somebody please help me so that I can avoid revision attribute?

Comment: You'lll need to supply more details. For example, how have you configured your resolver in the ivysettings file.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to avoiding using a revision number. Ivy's purpose is to perform dependency management based on an arifact's revision number :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ignore the revision and download a ZIP from a Jenkins server, I use a resolver (in `ivysettings.xml`) like

```
<url name="jenkins" m2compatible="true" checksums="">
    <artifact pattern="http://jenkins:8080/job/[organization]/ws/sources/[module]/*[ext]*/[artifact].[ext]" />
</url>
```

and a dependency (in `ivy.xml`) like

```
<dependency org="source-build" name="project" rev="+">
    <artifact name="project" type="zip" />
</dependency>
```

So I'm using `+` for the revision as `latest.release` just did not resolve correctly and an empty string (`rev=""`) worked but left the artifact with a trailing dash in the local cache, which I disliked.

Note that I also had to disable checksums in the resolver definition due to a [bug in Ivy](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1061).

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use "latest.integration" as the revision?